# How to upgrade Ubuntu 9.04 LTSP Thin client to Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, server, ltsp

I have a setup with Ubuntu 9.04 LTSP server and Ubuntu 9.04 LTSP Thin client.
I want to upgrade my Ubuntu 9.04 LTSP Thin client to Ubuntu 12.04 or higher.

Is it possible to upgrade? If it is, How can i do that?

Guide me on this.

Comment: from this site? ltsp.org - that would be off-topic for this site, but would be on-topic at unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: alternatively - if its standard ubuntu ... http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release that Q will solve your issue - you'll need to go through 9.10/10.04/12.04